# How to start postgres service as a different user(myown) instead postgres user

Tags: postgresql

I have installed postgres 9.5 in my linux(16.04) machine.I have started service using below command.

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

This will start postgres service as a postgres user.
But I want to run postgres a different user(myown user).

How can I do .Please help !!.

Answer (score 1):

You have to recursively change the ownership of the database directory to the new user.

If the WAL directory or tablespaces are outside the data directory, you have to change their ownership too.

Then you will have to configure the startup script so that it starts PostgreSQL as the new user. Watch out: if you installed the startup script with an installation package, any changes to it will probably be lost after an update.

I recommend that you don't do all that and continue running PostgreSQL as `postgres`.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. I have one more question where this postgres user creation will happen/in which file. If I can change user there itself then problem is solved right !!.

Comment: That is done my the server installation package. I don't think you want to roll your own, right?

Comment: I want to change the data_directory  path in file /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf.. data_directory= 'my/own/path'.only me/my-user can access that path,other user(postgres)  can't access that path.I want to start service with my user so that I can access that mounted path.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: I am installing postgres in a docker container .By default there is one data_directory path mentioned in /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf. I wanted to change that path and  point to new path on the mounted volume. which is out side the container .Only I/with my user  can access that volume no ther can access.So I wanted to start postgres with my user instead postgres.

Comment: What's keeping you from doing that?

Comment: I done all the necessary changes and started the service.I am getting below error. arun@postgresmaster-66d4bd49db-99gmq:~$ service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 10 database server
 * Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl start -D /persistent/arun/post_test/postgresql/10/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf"  exited with status 1:
   ...fail!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177344/discussion-between-khumar-and-laurenz-albe).

Comment: Look into the log. For testing, don't start with pg_ctl, start "postgres" itself.